# Creating a non-db bool attribute in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have a case where I'm defining a non-db attribute in my model:

```
  def is_preview
    @is_preview = full_url.nil? || 'preview'.in?(full_url)
  end
```

Now since this is boolean, the Ruby convention is to set it as preview? We're using rubocop so I have to go with the convention, so I keep getting an error here. What is the Ruby way to create a boolean non-db attribute in a model?

Comment: Yes, a common convention is to name such a method `preview?` instead of `is_preview`. But even when Rubocop complains about `is_preview` it is only a common convention there is no technical reason to follow those conventions.

Comment: Is this actually a Rails question since you're talking about models? In Rails you would define an attribute using `ActiveModel::Attributes` - `attribute :preview, :boolean, default: false` which gives you all the typecasting goodness and generates a `preview?` method.